# API REST asp.net Mvc entityframework

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, asp.net-web-api

Estoy tratando de hacer el consumidor de un Api Rest. En el método **Edit** tengo el siguiente código:

```
   public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        ClassRespuesta proveedorID = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.43.173:49900/");
            //HTTP GET
            var responseTask = client.GetAsync("api/cliente/" + id.ToString());
            responseTask.Wait();

            var result = responseTask.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<ClassRespuesta>();

                readTask.Wait();

                proveedorID = readTask.Result;
            }
        }
```

Pero cuando ejecuto y voy a la vista **Edit** me devuelve el siguiente error:

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ConsumoRestApi.Models.ClassRespuesta' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

esta es mi clase

```
 public class ClassRespuesta
{
    public int proveedorID { get; set; }
    public string nombreProveedor { get; set; }
    public string direccionProveedor { get; set; }
    public string telefonoProveedor { get; set; }
    public string correoProveedor { get; set; }
}
```

y esto me devuelve cuando ejecuto con postman

```
PUT http://192.168.43.173:49900/api/cliente/1
{
    "$id": "1",
    "proveedorID": 0,
    "nombreProveedor": null,
    "direccionProveedor": null,
    "telefonoProveedor": 0,
    "correoProveedor": null,
    "Producto": []
}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado esa API utilizando alguna herramienta como Postman? El error dice que espera un JSON a modo de clase y le mandas un arreglo. ¿Esa api tiene documentación que puedas revisar?

Comment: la api funciona con postman, estoy creando la vista de editar, para que me pase todos los datos a esa vista. pero cuando entro a la vista me tira ese error. He visto algunas paginas de informacion pero todas tiene la misma estructura que la que tengo y sin embargo cuando trato de ingresar a esa vista me tira el error ya mencionado

Comment: Vamos a necesitar 2 cosas: La clase `ClassRespuesta` con todos sus atributos y la respuesta que genera esa API desde postman (cuando funciona). Con esto podemos darte una mejor respuesta

Comment: `public class ClassRespuesta
    {
        public int proveedorID { get; set; }
        public string nombreProveedor { get; set; }
        public string direccionProveedor { get; set; }
        public string telefonoProveedor { get; set; }
        public string correoProveedor { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega la información solicitada. Falta un ejemplo de respuesta del JSON de ese servicio. Saludos

Comment: ¿Seguro que mandas un PUT? En tu código veo un GET...

Comment: lo que estoy haciendo es que cuando hagan click en editar, este pase a la vista con todos los datos que estan en la lista y luego edite los datos

Comment: porque desde codigo veo un `GetAsync()` pero desde postman usas un PUT ? la pregunta seria, no te estas llamando a si mismo, en que contexto esta ese action `Edit` que has puesto de codigo? entiendo tienes dos web project separados con distinto puerto, uno es un `asp.net mvc` y el otro un `webapi`, no?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini si son dos web, el contexto del edit es para obtener los datos que se visualizan en la lista en la vista de edit, para que cuando se muestre la vista edit muestre los datos de la lista pero que puedan editarse

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaria que como primer paso obtengas la respuesta como `string` para poder evaluar que estructura tiene el `json`, para eso usarias:

```
var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

entonces pon un breakpoint en el codigo he inspecciona el string que obtienes como respuesta

Puede ser que el json que esperas no tenga la estructura de la clase a la cual intentas deserializar